# In an XSD setting the Schema for an 'any' part of the tree without explicitly naming the elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a situation where I think it is a good idea to allow any element name to be valid as a child element.

What I have in mind is something like this

```
<attributes> 
  <foo> 
    <screenName>Foo thing</screenName>
    <value>1234</value>
  </foo> 
  <bar> 
    <screenName>Bar thing</screenName>
    <value>abcd</value>
  </bar>
</attributes>
```

The elements in question (foo and bar) are attributes of something that can be freely added by end users. The element names I intend to have are a sanitized version of the original attribute names.

Although I want the names of those elements to be dynamic. I still want all of them to follow a schema (in this example: Have the mandatory fields screenName and value).

As far as I can figure out ( [I had a look at this](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp) ) an 'any' thing in an XSD is essentially a 'black hole' where you can throw anything in without any restrictions.

The only way to set restrictions if I were to define an XSD schema for both 'foo' and 'bar' in my example. Due to the number of possible attributes (thousands) I do not want to explicitly define all of them, yet I still would like to have the restrictions.

Is this possible to define in an XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

**Cannot** be directly expressed; `xsd:any` means *any* markup and cannot be further constrained.  One would have to check with code outside of the XSD.

### XSD 1.1

**Can** be directly expressed via `xsd:assert`:

```
<xs:assert test="every $e in * 
                 satisfies (exists($e/screenName) and exists($e/value))"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I find it strange that you apparently cannot specify a 'normal' schema for this usecase.